# Gradle unable to resolve artifact due to missing POM file in repository

Tags: maven, gradle, repository, pom.xml, artifact

I'm encountering an issue with Gradle while attempting to resolve an artifact from a remote repository (declared as maven repository). The artifact seems to be present in the repository, but the associated POM file is missing. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Could not resolve com.test.log:log:22.03.00.00.
> Could not get resource 'https://repo.custom.io/release/com/test/log/log/22.03.00.00/log-22.03.00.00.pom'.
```

Despite the presence of the artifact in the repository, Gradle is failing to locate the POM file, resulting in this resolution error. How can I resolve this issue and successfully retrieve the artifact without the associated POM file? Any insights or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Note: I dont have access to the repository so I cant add the pom file to repository